# Convert a text to lowercase but keep uppercase for word that was uppercase

Tags: c#, string

I'm searching for a function in c# that convert to lowercase a string, but keep uppercase the word that originally was uppercase.

```
"Pippo, pluto. paperino" -> "pippo, pluto. paperino"
"Pippo, PLUTO. paperino" -> "pippo, PLUTO. paperino"
```

but if all word is Uppercase then convert to lowercase.

```
"PIPPO, PLUTO. PAPERINO" -> "pippo, pluto. paperino"
```

I found the solution below. I've consider also all the separator. What do you think?

```
private static string buildSourceString(string sourceString)
    {
        sourceString += " ";
        var sb = new StringBuilder(sourceString.Length);
        int nOfCharWord = 0;
        int nOfCharLower = 0;
        int nWord = 0;
        int nWordUpper = 0;

        foreach (var c in sourceString)
        {
            if (c == '.' | c == ',' | c == ';' | c == ':' | c == '!' | c == '?' | c == '\n' | c == '\r' || Char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
            {
                if (nOfCharWord > 0)
                    nWord++;
                if (nOfCharWord > 0 && nOfCharWord.Equals(nOfCharLower))
                {

                    for (int i = sb.Length - nOfCharWord; i < sb.Length; i++)
                    {
                        sb[i] = char.ToUpper(sb[i]);
                    }
                    nWordUpper++;
                }
                // reset contatori
                nOfCharWord = 0;
                nOfCharLower = 0;
                sb.Append(c);

            }
            else
            {
                if (c.ToString().Equals(c.ToString().ToUpper()))
                {

                    sb.Append(char.ToLower(c));
                    nOfCharLower++;
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.Append(c);
                }
                nOfCharWord++;
            }
        }
        if (nWord == nWordUpper)
        {
            sb = new StringBuilder(sourceString.Length);
            sb = sb.Append(sourceString.ToLower());
        }

        sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: You could use a flag for checking if all words are fully uppercase, and cycle through the words while using `Char.IsUpper()`. Or you can use LINQ's `All` method.

Comment: Have you tried writing anything that does what you ask for?

Comment: There is no "stock" function in .Net to do what you are asking.  You will have to write something yourself.  There are any number of approaches, what have you tried?

Comment: @Matt3o you're saying 'MY case converter `"hi. i'm Matteo and work in IP"`, but the code you post don't do that, it does `"Hi. I'm Matteo and work in IP"` with IP in upper. That is the same, as you told us the PPT case.

Comment: The questions you ask in the beginning don't match with your samples in the end and your intended algorithm. Please edit your question to make it more consistent.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static bool  IsAllUpper(string input)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        if (Char.IsLetter(input[i]) && !Char.IsUpper(input[i]))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public static string GetString(String input)
{
    var arr = input.Split(' ');
    var result = "";

    foreach(var item in arr)
    {
        if(IsAllUpper(item))
            result += ' ' + item;
        else
            result += ' ' + item.ToLower();


    }
    return result;
}

public static void Main()
{
    String s1 = "Pippo, pluto. paperino";
    String s2 = "Pippo, PLUTO. paperino";
    String s3 = "PIPPO, PLUTO. PAPERINO";



    Console.WriteLine(GetString(s1));
    Console.WriteLine(GetString(s2));
    Console.WriteLine(GetString(s3));


}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will convert any lower-case words at the beginning of sentences to make the beginning of the word in caps. For example:

> hi. i'm Matteo and work in IP.

will be converted to

> Hi. I'm Matteo and work in IP.

Similarly,

> hi. i'm Matteo and work in IP. please direct your QUESTIONS to me. feel free to email, Or phone.

will convert to:

> Hi. I'm Matteo and work in IP. Please direct your QUESTIONS to me. Feel free to email, Or phone.

The best way to approach this sort of specific string manipulation in your question would be to use the [Regex class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I'd suggest looking at MSDN's minimal documentation of how to use regular expressions in .NET. If you're not familiar with how to use regular expressions in general, there is much help that can be found via your favorite search engine.

I'll illustrate using your last example. To dovetail into an example provided by MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (illustrating a `Replace()` overload):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string original = "hi. i'm Matteo and work in IP";
        Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(original, @"\A[a-z]|(?<=\W{2})[a-z]", new MatchEvaluator(CapText), RegexOptions.ECMAScript));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static string CapText(Match match)
    {
        string tempStr = match.ToString();
        if (char.IsLower(tempStr[0]))
        {
            return char.ToUpper(tempStr[0]) + tempStr.Substring(1, tempStr.Length - 1);
        }
        return tempStr;
    }
}
```

The two key pieces are the regular expression in `Regex.Replace` and the `CapText` custom evaluator method.

The regular expression in `Regex.Replace` could be broken down as follows:

- \A[a-z] finds a lowercase letter a through z at the beginning of a string.
- | is the alternation / OR operand, so either logic before or after it applies.
- (?<=\W{2}) is the positive [lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html), that searches for exactly two non-word characters before the following set...
- ...which is the last [a-z], which searches for a lowercase letter a through z.

Answer (score 0):

I love TDD :-)
Using **your parameters** I reach this class:

```
internal static class ToLowerEx
{
    static readonly Regex Words = new Regex(@"(?'item'\b\w+\b)|(?'item'\b\W+\b)", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
    public static string Get(string text)
    {
        if (!Words.IsMatch(text)) return text;

        var result = new StringBuilder();
        var matches = Words.Matches(text);
        foreach (Match match in matches)
            result.Append(ProcessWord(match.Value));

        return result.ToString();
    }
    private static string ProcessWord(string text)
    {
        return !text.All(char.IsUpper)
            ? text.ToLower()
            : text;
    }
}
```

Just in case you get interested, these are the tests:

```
[TestFixture]
internal class LowerTests
{
    [Test]
    public void Test_asdf_asdf()
    {
        var actual = ToLowerEx.Get("asdf");
        const string expected = "asdf";
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test_Asdf_asdf()
    {
        var actual = ToLowerEx.Get("Asdf");
        const string expected = "asdf";
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test_aSdf_asdf()
    {
        var actual = ToLowerEx.Get("aSdf");
        const string expected = "asdf";
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test_ASDF_ASDF()
    {
        var actual = ToLowerEx.Get("ASDF");
        const string expected = "ASDF";
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test_asdfAndqwer_asdfAandqwer()
    {
        var actual = ToLowerEx.Get("asdf, qwer");
        const string expected = "asdf, qwer";
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test_AsdfAndqWer_asdfAandqwer()
    {
        var actual = ToLowerEx.Get("Asdf, qWer");
        const string expected = "asdf, qwer";
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test_AsdfAndQWER_asdfAandQWER()
    {
        var actual = ToLowerEx.Get("Asdf, QWER");
        const string expected = "asdf, QWER";
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow below code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String s1 = "Pippo, pluto. paperino";
    String s2 = "Pippo, PLUTO. paperino";
    String s3 = "PIPPO, PLUTO. PAPERINO";

    MessageBox.Show(myStringConverter(s1));
    MessageBox.Show(myStringConverter(s2));
    MessageBox.Show(myStringConverter(s3));
}


public string myStringConverter(string str)
{
    string[] strArray = str.Split(' '); // Word is always seprate by Space.
    string Answer = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < strArray.Length; i++)
    {
        string tempStr = strArray[i];
        var withoutSpecialCharacter = new string(tempStr.Where(c => Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || Char.IsWhiteSpace(c)).ToArray());
        if (!withoutSpecialCharacter.All(char.IsUpper))
        {
            Answer += strArray[i].ToLower() + " ";
        }
        else
        {
            Answer += strArray[i] + " ";
        }
    }
    return Answer;
}
```